# Git equivalent to TFS Shelve before trying something risky

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

In TFS, I used to shelve my changes as a back-up before trying something risky or experimenting with something.

If everything went okay, I just deleted the shelve. Otherwise, I unshelved the back-up and continued.

I wasn't interested in sharing those changes with anybody.

What would be the equivalent operation in Git? I'm using VS2015 with GitHub extension, by the way.

Comment: I have no idea about Visual Studio, but in Git, you just make a commit. Commits are cheap, you can make them and then stop using them if you decide you don't like them after all. To manage them, make them on branches. Branches are cheap, you can make them and then stop using them (or even delete them) if you decide you don't like them after all. (You literally *can't* delete commits, but once you delete the way to *see* them, i.e., the branch names that let you them, you won't see them, and after a month or so they will really go away.)

Answer (score 5):

Create a branch.  Let's say you're working on `master`, and you decide you want to experiment with a solution.  Create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b my-spiffy-new-feature
```

Now, continue your work on the `my-spiffy-new-feature` branch.  What if suddenly you have a brilliant idea for a *completely different* solution?  Just create a new branch from `master`, either by running:

```
git checkout -b another-awesome-feature master
```

Or equivalently:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b another-awesome-feature
```

In either case, do all the work on your branch.  If you decide you like the feature, merge it back into the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge my-spiffy-new-feature
```

You can let the branches hang around, or you can delete them if they are no longer of interest:

```
git branch -d my-spiffy-new-feature
```

Note that the above will fail if you try to delete a branch that you haven't merged into it's upstream branch (that is, the branch from which it originated); if you *really* want to delete a branch, even though you haven't merged it:

```
git branch -D another-awesome-feature
```

Comment: ... and because you're coming from TFS, be aware that a Git branch is a _very_ lightweight object, it's basically just a pointer on the history. So creating a new branch from master does not involve any network operation, and almost no disk operation either. So don't be afraid of creating branches. You can create and dispose of branches as it pleases you.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to TFVC - Shelvesets in git I feel is `stash`. As others have already mentioned that it has it's own disadvantages, one being that it is not branch specific. But still it is a good alternative depending on your requirement.

In **Visual Studio 2019** - if you are looking for a quick way not to commit your changes to the current branch yet, and want to save your change for later, you can use [stash](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/10/the-git-stash-functionality-in-visual-studio-2019/) like this.

[image]

In Team Explorer, you have two options for `stash`:

1. Stash All - creates a stash that contains all the uncommitted changes, and it also undoes all the uncommitted changes in your branch
2. Stash All and Keep Staged (--keep-index) - creates a stash that contains all the uncommitted changes and also keep the changes in the branch that you have already staged for a commit

[image]

To get your `stash` back, you can right click on your stash under `Stashes` section. It will give you some options:

1. View Changes - shows all the changes in the stash
2. Apply - applies the changes to the branch and it will keep the stash
3. Pop -  Apply the stash and finally Drop it (see `Drop` below)
4. Drop - deletes the stash

`Apply` and `Pop` options have two sub-options:

1. Apply/Pop and Restore Staged - applies/pops the changes to your branch and ensures that files that were staged before are staged again
2. Apply/Pop All as Unstaged – applies/pops the changes to your branch and it won’t stage the files that you had staged before.

Credit: Thomas Claudius Huber's article. [Link again](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/10/the-git-stash-functionality-in-visual-studio-2019/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), it allows you to push and pop changes onto a stack.

However I would recommend just committing with a releveant commit message.
You can always rework and squash your commits before you push.  I never remember what or why I stashed without the commit messages.

Comment: The disadvantage of stash being that it's not branch-specific and shared among the repo. I prefer the branch solution, which is best but of course does not seem logical if you don't understand how lightweight a branch is in Git compared to TFS or SVN.

Comment: I also prefer the branch, and use stash for quick works in progress to avoid commit hooks, but just wanted to note that you can stash with a message too just like a commit message.